Multiple HTML Elements with a single handle javascript functions
Is it possible for different HTML elements to call the same javascript functions, and if so, how can we differentiate which event was being called?
For example...
<input id="input1" type="text" onchange="{!c.handleOnCHange}" />

<input id="input2" type="text" onchange="{!c.handleOnCHange}" />

<input id="input3" type="text" onchange="{!c.handleOnCHange}" />

And then in the controller have something like...
handleOnCHange : function(component,event,helper) {


   if(value is from input 1){
    //do some logic

   } else if (value is from input 2){
    //do some logic

   } else if (value is from input 3){
    //do some logic

   }
}


Add data-id on each component.
On javascript side, just ask for the data id.
Example :
<input id="input1" type="text" data-id="txtTest1" onchange="{!c.handleInputChange}" />

<input id="input2" type="text" data-id="txtTest2" onchange="{!c.handleInputChange}" />

<input id="input3" type="text" data-id="txtTest3" onchange="{!c.handleInputChange}" />

The handleInputChange function should look like :
 handleInputChange(objEvent) {
        if(objEvent.target.dataset.id === 'txtTest1') {
            this.test1 = objEvent.target.value;
        } else if(objEvent.target.dataset.id === 'txtTest2') {
            this.test2 = objEvent.target.value;
        } else if(objEvent.target.dataset.id === 'txtTest3') {
             this.test3 = objEvent.target.value;
        } 
    }


This worked! Thank you
